# Something goes wrong with filter, not saving data

Tags: php, mysql

I made some code for filter my prices, but its not save that filter, i post information, and when i refresh, all lost. And its show only one page for filter, i know the are more items, but it show only one page.

```
if(isset($_POST['sort'])){
    $cena_no = trim($_POST['fl_cena_no']);
    $cena_lidz = trim($_POST['fl_cena_lidz']);
        if(empty($cena_lidz)){
            $cena_lidz = '99999999999999999999999999999999';
        }
        if(empty($cena_no)){
                $cena_no = '0';
        }
            $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
            $pages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zirglietas_pardod");
            $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages, 0) / 15);
            $querystring = "";
            foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != "page") $querystring .= "$key=$value&amp;";
            }
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM zirglietas_pardod WHERE cena >= $cena_no AND cena <= $cena_lidz ORDER BY cena ASC LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * 15) . ", 15 ");
}
```

Mby need add session?

(p.s after 2 hours i will be back, and i can answer for replies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuhu, now session save data, cooking up some code...

```
if(isset($_POST['sort'])){
     $cena_no = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['fl_cena_no']));
     $cena_lidz = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['fl_cena_lidz']));
        if(empty($cena_lidz)){
        $cena_lidz = '99999999999999999999999999999999';
        }
        if(empty($cena_no)){
        $cena_no = '0';
        }
        $_SESSION['sort'] = $_POST;
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM zirglietas_pardod WHERE cena >= $cena_no AND cena <= $cena_lidz ORDER BY cena ASC");
        }
```

And read up

```
if (isset($_SESSION['sort'])){
        $cena_no = $_SESSION['sort']['fl_cena_no'];
        $cena_lidz = $_SESSION['sort']['fl_cena_lidz'];
        if(empty($cena_lidz)){
        $cena_lidz = '99999999999999999999999999999999';
        }
        if(empty($cena_no)){
        $cena_no = '0';
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM zirglietas_pardod WHERE cena >= $cena_no AND cena <= $cena_lidz ORDER BY cena ASC");
                        }
```

And destroy session, now i can work to next thing :)